# Why [\D\S] is not the same as [^\d\s] in regex?

Tags: regex

I was reading Regular expression from http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html . Its written there that `[\D\S]` is not the same as `[^\d\s]`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the paragraph?

Comment: It already explains there precisely how they are different.

Comment: `[\D\S]` will try to match a character that is **not a digit** or **not a space**. Any character will satisfy atleast one of those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the link you posted..

> The latter will match any character that is not a digit or
>   whitespace. So it will match x, but not 8. The former, however, will
>   match any character that is either not a digit, or is not whitespace.
>   Because a digit is not whitespace, and whitespace is not a digit,
>   [\D\S] will match any character, digit, whitespace or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`\D` is all non digits. `\S` is all non space. `[ <something> <something else> ]` is grouping meaning *either* `<something>` *or* `<something else>`.

So `[\D\S]` is either non-digits or non-space.

And `[^\d\s]` is *neither* digits nor space.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the reference

> Because a digit is not whitespace, and whitespace is not a digit,
>   [\D\S] will match any character, digit, whitespace or otherwise.

Might be a clue